# How to clip Image or cut unwanted parts?

Tags: image, wrapper, smalltalk, cut, clipping

How to do that in Smalltalk? I was trying to do it using BoundedWrapper, but image was not appearing. Can Image use BoundedWrapper? Or: Is a method to cut Image without wrapping?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a custom view, you can use displayOn:at: to display the image at an offset within the bounds of the control.  VisualWorks should clip the image automatically.